# Sending progress to renderer process in electron-dl

Tags: download, electron

I've recently tried to use electron-dl to handle content update of my electron app. I'm trying to show the download percentage to the user in renderer process but I couldn't find the right syntax to send it from the main process.

My current code is:

**Main Process:**

```
ipcMain.on("downloadUpdate", (event, info) => {
  download(BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), info.url, info.properties)
    .then(dl => event.sender.send("updateDownloadCompleted", dl.getSavePath()));
});
```

**Renderer Process:**

```
ipcRenderer.send("downloadUpdate", {
  url: "https://testurl.co/test.zip",
    properties: {
      directory:"/temp/updates",
        filename:"test.zip",
        showBadge:false,
        onProgress:function(){
          console.log("hi");
        },
      }
    });
```

I don't know how to send the progress to the renderer process.

Any help is appreciated...

***Edit 1:***
I found that the problem is that the *onProgress* parameter is not read as a function in main process. Does anyone knows a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

if you print your info.properties, I guess it will be no onProgress property.

try something like this should be work. Remove onProgress from properties config and add it later.

```
ipcMain.on("downloadUpdate", (event, info) => {
    info.properties.onProgress = function() {
        console.log('hi');
    }
    download(BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), info.url, info.properties)
    .then(dl => event.sender.send("updateDownloadCompleted", dl.getSavePath()));
});
```